# Why is std::slice_array::operator= const?

Tags: c++, constants, slice, member-functions, valarray

[All overloads of assignment operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/slice_array/operator%3D) of `std::slice_array` are const member functions, but why is it designed so?

Maybe the reason is that `std::slice_array` is designed to be a proxy class, and these assignment operators just modify the referred elements without modifying the proxy class itself, so they are reasonable to be const member functions. However, why are [those compound operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/slice_array/operator_arith) of `std::slice_array` **not** const member functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first question, `slice_array` is just a proxy class. It has reference semantics, so none of its actual members are modified by any operation, so marking everything `const` gives you more usability.

For the second question, all of the operators *are* declared `const` (per the [current working draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/template.slice.array.overview) and back to [C++11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/template.slice.array.overview)). For the same reason that the assignment operators are `const`. This is just a bug in cppreference misidentifying them. Happens.